# Trello + Google Calendar + iPhone Calendar

Tags: trello, synchronization, iphone

I need your advice about how to do following actions:

As a trello user I want to synchronize my Trello cards with my Google Calendar and my iPhone calendar, so that keeps me in touch with all my activities.

Example:
Given I added some card in Trello.
When I set up due date option.
Then this card automatically created as event in my Google Calendar And shows in my iPhone calendar.

Comment: Just to verify, it works on Google Calendar, and you want to synch Google Calendar with your iPhone?

Comment: Not exactly, Tool: https://trellocalendar-francois2metz.dotcloud.com/# generete to you a link of trello board calendar and you can add it in your google calendar as "other calendar" by this instruction: http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37100 So in your google calendar will be present 2 types of calendars: 1. Your personal 2. Other Trello calendar. It doesn't integrate trello calendar in google. You can just read only and it is satisfied me. The question is how I can setup trello calendar in my iPhone?

Comment: I find the way how to set up!!!! Please see root message

Comment: Please add your answer as an answer rather than tacking it onto the end of your question - this makes it easier for others to find and read (you can accept your own answer).

Answer (score 9):

For Google Calendar sync using this tool: https://trellocalendar-francois2metz.dotcloud.com/# Just add new "other calendar" and put there the ics link from tool (ICS Feed)

Caution: It updates each few hours, so do not panic if you change something in trello but it doesnt change in google calendar at once

For iPhone:
Before: You done first step and you have a ics link from tool 
1. Settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calendars -> Add Account 
2. Select Other -> Subscribed Calendar. Paste ics link from tool without this symbols [only_me=false&not_archived=false] in the end of link, after [ics?]. If you want alarm you can live it [&alarm=-PT0M]

Example of link: https://trellocalendar-francois2metz.dotcloud.com/calendar/blablabla/my-board.ics?alarm=-PT0M 4. Touch Save

Cautions: It updates automatically, just try to wait for a minute or open close calendar app in the iPhone.

P.S. All your ideas and question about trello + google calendar sync you can ask here: trello.com/card/ideas-enter-a-comment-here/4f0d53d03ca0f7f83f03cad0/4

Answer (score 7):

Calendar is now supported naively in Trello. See http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/articles/1262881-viewing-cards-in-a-calendar-view. There's an iCalendar feed you can paste into Google calendar.

Comment: Is there a way to obtain an iCalendar feed containing events from all boards in an organization? Up to now we are only able to get distinct feeds from each board.